# Change image based on screen size (Bootstrap template)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a site using this bootstrap template: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

I have filled the 'carousel' with images but when I view on mobile the images become squashed and poor quality. I have tried to change the image using javascript based on the screen size but it has had no effect.

Is there another way I can change the image seen on mobile?

Here is the HTML:

> ```
>  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
>     <div class="item active">
>       <img id="banner" class="first-slide" src="graphics/banner1.gif" alt="First slide">
>       <div class="container">
>         <div class="carousel-caption">
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
> ```

Here is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
if ((screen.width<=800) && (screen.height<=600)) {
// Make sure banner is ready in the DOM
document.getElementById('banner').src="graphics/banner2.gif"; }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You've got a code for us to look at?

Comment: CSS media queries is one. A vague answer, for a vague question

Comment: @Epirocks I need to change the src of the image. as far as i understand that can't be changed through CSS is that correct?

Comment: Well bigger images should be ok to be resized to smaller. I've never seen an issue with that in a browser. It depends what you mean by "squashed" and "poor quality". Is it maintaining aspect ratio? Also is it using "src" or using "background-image". The other thing thing is, you can load both thumbs and full images and use CSS to hide one and show the other with media queries.

Comment: Yes its the change of ratio that ruins the image. Its no problem as i have other images for the mobile view. Its using src in HTML not a background image.

Comment: don't the images have height:auto to keep their aspect ratio?

Comment: “Responsive images” would be a good research key phrase …

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS instead of making JS work more than it should:

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) , screen and (max-height: 600px){
  .myclass{ 
     width:500px;
     height:300px;
     background-image: #ffffff url("banner1.gif") no-repeat left top;
  }
}
```

And then the HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
   <div id="banner" class="first-slide myclass" />
   <div class="container">
     <div class="carousel-caption" />
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is this just to change the size of the image? I would like to change the image entirely if possible?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the image as a background of a div... so we change the `<img>` to `<div>` and set the background to w/e we want. I editted my answer to reflect this